# New Cert for company VPN, now openconnect does not work

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco

So thanks to an "upgrade" at work,  we got a new VPN certificate.  It is self-signed,  and it no longer works.  Here is the syslog:

```
openconnect[6002]: Connected to xxx:443
openconnect[6002]: SSL negotiation with xxx
openconnect[6002]: Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
openconnect[6002]: Connected to HTTPS on xxx
openconnect[6002]: Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
openconnect[6002]: CSTP connected. DPD 300, Keepalive 30
NetworkManager[1273]: Set up DTLS failed; using SSL instead
openconnect[6002]: Connected as 192.168.0.160, using SSL
openconnect[6002]: SIOCSIFMTU: Operation not permitted
NetworkManager[1273]: <info>  [1537565026.6078] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
NetworkManager[1273]: <info>  [1537565026.6106] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",7:(vpn0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
NetworkManager[1273]: <warn>  [1537565026.6107] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",7:(vpn0)]: invalid IP4 config received!
NetworkManager[1273]: <warn>  [1537565026.6107] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",7:(vpn0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
NetworkManager[1273]: <info>  [1537565026.6129] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
NetworkManager[1273]: <info>  [1537565026.6133] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
NetworkManager[1273]: <info>  [1537565026.6134] vpn-connection[0x55ab83c186c0,a0614dc2-f483-4dc9-87d4-7b9ac4169d31,"company",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

I see the signer not found error,  but it moves past that to "invalid IP4 config received!"  what's going on here and how do I fix it?

Or better yet,  tell openconnect to trust a self signed cert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a workaround to use the --servercert option when connecting:

in terminal enter

```
sudo openconnect --protocol=gp <hostaddress>
```

and get the message:

```
Certificate from VPN server "serverhost" failed verification. 
Reason:   signer not found To trust this server in future, perhaps
add this to your command line: --servercert pin-sha256:serverfingerprint 
Enter 'sì' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:
```

and then finally use the fingerprint in your command line option:

```
openconnect --servercert=sha1:26cfbcdefg... [usual arguments]
```

or

```
openconnect --servercert=sha256:a8cfbcdedeadbeefdeadbeeffg... [usual arguments]
```

Source https://github.com/dlenski/openconnect/issues/60

Comment: for openconnect --protocol=gp  I get Unknown VPN protocol 'gp'  --  I have been using the gnome UI to do this,  I have never done the command line,  so i need VERY detailed instructions. :)

Comment: You are clearly running a version of openconnect without GlobalProtect support.

You need globalprotect option - download and install the Ubuntu/Debian packages. Try to remove openconnect in your package manager or sudo apt remove openconnect and install it again sudo apt install openconnect.

Comment: Im on Ubuntu 18.04.1  -- and removing and updating, I still get an unknown protocol,  I checked the version, 7.08-3  which is the latest.  What else could be wrong?

Comment: Follow the build instructions on: https://github.com/dlenski/openconnect/

Comment: Ok, I will get it from there.

Comment: That worked,  Next question is how to get this to work with network-manager-openconnect-gnome.  When I am connected like you said,  all traffic is going through the VPN,  which is strict with its ports, so I can't Slack for example.  Is there a way to create a .crt file that I can add to the network-manager-openconnect-gnome?

Comment: That did not work.  I also tried this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304503/how-to-pull-vpn-certificate-to-put-in-cert-store  and that did not work with the GUI.   So I don't have a problem with running a script every morning,  but I have to use my regular internet for every other call not beginning with 10.x.x.x  Any idea how to do that on the command line?

Comment: * CA cert: openssl pkcs12 -in aab3w.p12 -nodes -cacerts -outuva_cacert.pem
     * Cert: openssl pkcs12 -in aab3w.p12 -nodes -clcerts -out aab3w_cert.pem
     * Key: openssl pkcs12 -in aab3w.p12 nodes -nocerts -out aab3w_key.pem

Comment: You can exctract the certificate from p12 PKCS 12 file.