# network-manager won't connect with self-signed cert

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I had an openconnect VPN working until they chaged the cert.  It's self signed and my syslog looks like this:

```
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.5306] settings-connection[0x55a6b75f3520,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457]: write: successfully updated (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN 1 (28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1")), connection was modified in the process
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.5353] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.5370] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
openconnect[9838]: Connected to 34.196.133.252:443
openconnect[9838]: SSL negotiation with 34.196.133.252
openconnect[9838]: Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
openconnect[9838]: Connected to HTTPS on 34.196.133.252
openconnect[9838]: Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
NetworkManager[777]: Set up DTLS failed; using SSL instead
openconnect[9838]: CSTP connected. DPD 300, Keepalive 30
openconnect[9838]: Connected as 192.168.0.173, using SSL
openconnect[9838]: SIOCSIFMTU: Operation not permitted
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.8559] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.8582] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",4:(vpn0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
NetworkManager[777]: <warn>  [1537936242.8583] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",4:(vpn0)]: invalid IP4 config received!
NetworkManager[777]: <warn>  [1537936242.8584] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",4:(vpn0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.8606] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.8608] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
NetworkManager[777]: <info>  [1537936242.8608] vpn-connection[0x55a6b7806330,28292c55-ffbf-4639-bffb-369cc7196457,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

Now I posted this similar here:  [New Cert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077360/new-cert-for-company-vpn-now-openconnect-does-not-work/1077399?noredirect=1#comment1769781_1077399)  and I followed the instructions given.  However, I installed a 3rd party openconnect, and even though it worked,  it broke my network manager (the lib dependencies were having problems) it broke the Gnome GUI, and I could not split tunnel it.  So I need another way.  I was able to connect with this command:

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/openconnect -u me --servercert pin-sha256:1eq6Zy8FGCoEabDB/RnGydqzRMi5TSOpBNAGxm1ivFg=
```

And that worked,  but does not work with the distro oppenconnect. How can I turn that pin-sha256 blurb into a .crt or .pem  or something that the regular openconnect will handle?

**UPDATE**  I can connect on the command line with sudo:

```
 sudo openconnect -u <name> <ip>
```

So I am guessing that the Network Manager is not running as root.  How do I do that?