# VPN seems to work but my ip is still the same and some urls are inaccessible, they should not be

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to set up a vpn on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have a pfx file that is secured with a password. I generate a certificate and key in the following way:

For the certificate:

`openssl pkcs12 -in my.pfx -nokeys -out publiccert.pem -nodes`

For the key:

`openssl pkcs12 -in my.pfx -nocerts -out privatekey.pem -nodes`

In the vpn settings:

*General*:

**VPN Protocol**: Cisco AnyConnect

**Gateway**: [vpn.something.com]

**User Certificate**: publiccert.pem

**Private Key**: privatekey.pem

When I try turning on the vpn I get an error saying that the certificate failed to validate, no signer found. And when I type my username and password, it seems to turn on successfully but my ip address doesn't get changed.

I would appreciate any help. I'm just clueless....

EDIT:

I followed the link and tried running the command provided there, here is the output I got:

Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Empty response from server
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie

Comment: You will need to sign the certificate, otherwise the client cannot accept it. Google for creating self signed certificate.

Comment: @kukulo if the VPN server just blindly accepts any locally generated certificate then there is a serious authentication problem...

Comment: Who manages the VPN server? Ask them about which certificate to use, or to sign yours or to give you the needed certificate. You can not expect just using blindly any certificate, this has to be coordinated with the provider of the VPN.

Comment: @kukulo well the pfx file was given me by the company I work in. Isn't it supposed to be signed?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be signed. I wrongly assumed that you did your own vpn server.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek well they've given me a pfx file but didn't tell me how exactly to extract it. I used the above mentioned commands that generated a key and certificate. I'm able to access some urls that I'm normally not, but some are inaccessible.

Comment: @user68186 The so called IT guy told me that he doesn't know how to do it on linux...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077360/new-cert-for-company-vpn-now-openconnect-does-not-work/1077399#1077399

Comment: "they've given me a pfx file but didn't tell me how exactly to extract it. " and "I'm able to access some urls that I'm normally not, but some are inaccessible." You might have more problems in the future with this VPN setup than just the certificate handling. "The so called IT guy told me that he doesn't know how to do it on linux.." He could also have extracted the certificate and key for you, on his side...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek He could but I'm not sure. This certificate I got from another guy who is a colleague of mine. He said it should work. Maybe there's something wrong with the way I extract the key and cert from the pfx file?

Comment: @kukulo I tried to follow the instructions and I got the output I describe in my EDIT. Would you please have a look at it?

Comment: What is your message after: sudo openconnect --protocol=gp <hostaddress>  ?

Comment: @kukulo I've added it to my question but here it is `Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect Empty response from server Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie`

Comment: @kukulo I tried it one more time and the last few lines are somewhat different now:

`Please enter your username and password.
Certificate Validation Failure
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie`

Comment: try to add the --os=win option after  sudo openconnect --protocol=gp --os=win <hostaddress>

Comment: reference: https://github.com/dlenski/openconnect/issues/131